# Is it possible to get a random element from an enum class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Like the title says:

```
class Answers {
    enum class Answer(text: String) {
        YES("Yes."),
        No("No."),
        MAYBE("Maybe."),
        AGAIN("Ask again.")
    }
    val answers = Answer.values()
    val rand = Random()
    fun genAnswer ():String {
        val n = rand.nextInt(3)+1
//        return Answer[answers[n]].text
    }
}
```

I want to pick an enum element randomly and return its text property. However, it seems I can't use its value to retrieve the element.

Comment: Try `answers[n].text`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the property declaration. So it keeps telling me unresolved `text`

Comment: Yeah you're right, I did not notice the missing `val`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get a random enum value by doing:

```
val randomAnswer = Answer.values().toList().shuffled().first().text
```

Keep in mind that it goes for convenience over performance.

---

Remember to expose the `text` property with `val`. For now, it's just a constructor param:

```
enum class Answer(val text: String)
```

Comment: Note: this is actually not the best solution performance-wise as it allocates a separate list and processes all the items of the original array, which is not necessary if you only need a single random item. Don't use it in performance-critical code.

Comment: @hotkey fully agree - I will expand the answer

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that surely, this solution is enlightening.

Answer (score 16):

`Answer.values().random()` will do the job for you in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

When you write val/var within the constructor for a param, it declares a property inside the class. When you do not write it, it is simply a parameter passed to the primary constructor. So just add val to the constructor param text which will make it a property with a getter and above program will work..

```
import java.util.*

class Answers {
    enum class Answer(val text: String) {
        YES("Yes."),
        No("No."),
        MAYBE("Maybe."),
        AGAIN("Ask again.")
    }
    val answers: Array<Answer> = Answer.values()
    val rand = Random()

    fun genAnswer ():String {
        val n = rand.nextInt(3)+1
        return answers[n].text
    }
}

fun main(String: Array<String>) {
    print(Answers().genAnswer())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Kotlin 1.9, you can use `Answer.entries.random()` this to get random entry from your `enum`. If your Kotlin version is older than 1.9, you can use `Answer.values().random()`.

According to the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants), `Answer.entries` returns a `EnumEntries<Answer>` which is a specialized `List<Answer>`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this generic functions for any type of enum

```
/**
 * return random enum value of enum class T
 */
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> randomEnum(): T {
    val enumValues: Array<T> = enumValues()
    return enumValues[(0 until enumValues.size).random()]
}

/**
 * return random Int from start to end of range
 */
fun IntRange.random(): Int =
    Random().nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a Enum `SupportedLocale` with values for languages

I did it in 2 steps

Get a list of values for enum:

```
  val languages: Array<SupportedLocale> = SupportedLocale.values()
```

Now select random value using ordinate position

```
 val randomLocale = languages[Random().nextInt(languages.size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution that I have used is

```
enum class OPERATOR(val symbol:String){MULTIPLY("*"),DIVIDE("/"),ADD("+"),SUBTRACT("-"),REMINDER("-")}

private fun getRandomOperator():String{
        val limit=OPERATOR.values().size-1
        return OPERATOR.values()[IntRange(0,limit).random()].symbol
    }
```